# ExecuteNonQuery does not update Access Database

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

I am trying to update an access database using the following;

```
if(count > 0)
{         
   sqlQuery = "UPDATE facial_user SET facial_1=? WHERE username=?;";
   using (OleDbCommand com2 = new OleDbCommand(sqlQuery, dbConnection))
   {
      sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@facial_1", engine.imageToBase64String(new Bitmap(pictureBox.Image, new Size(pictureBox.Width / 10, pictureBox.Height / 10))));
      sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", userTextBox.Text);
      sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
   }
}
else
{
   sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO facial_user(id, username, facial_1) VALUES(@id, @username, @facial_1);";
   using (OleDbCommand com2 = new OleDbCommand(sqlQuery, dbConnection))
   {
      sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", (dataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count + 1).ToString());
      sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", userTextBox.Text);
      sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@facial_1", engine.imageToBase64String(new Bitmap(pictureBox.Image, new Size(pictureBox.Width, pictureBox.Height))));
      sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
   }
}
```

I am able to enter both conditionals without issues and exit them without errors. However, my database file does not reflect the changes after I closed the dbconnection.

Please advise.

Comment: Did you checked the user name exist in the table you are trying to update?

Comment: If you are sure the `Update` block is executed, than the only issue can be, that the `UserName` does not match your parameter.

Comment: allow me to elaborate my issue, i first have to read the db and check whether a record exists. if it does, count > 0, and update that particular record with update, else count = 0 and insert a new record. My program is able to determine which conditional to run so I am quite sure I am reading my database correctly. I just dont understand why I cant make changes. :(

Comment: Is the variable(i.e user name) used to get the count is same ? i.e  Is the same user name text box is used to get the count or different one?..

Comment: yea they are the same. how i derive the value of count is by performing a select count statement on the db to check if a particular username exists and then cast the result into an int class variable which is count

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the above comments?

Comment: If nothing else, ExecuteNonQuery return value may be used to see if any row or rows were affected by your update statement. If 0 is returned the where condition most likely could not be satisfied as userTextBox text contained data not located in the database table.

Answer (score 0):

If the `INSERT` statement works and the `UPDATE` statement does not, the only possible solution is that there is no entry for the given `username`. So nothing is updated if the `WHERE` condition can not match the user name.

Comment: if there were no entry for the given username then the else condtional would have run instead. the issue I am facing is that my db cannot reflect any changes after going through either statements

Comment: @jazy1992 Are you sure that you don't have a surrounding transaction you're aborting or something like that? The statements look fine so they should execute well.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar I executed another query before the snippet i pasted which is to count the number of records that contain the same username. that worked well and gave me the correct count to allow me to run the codes i pasted.

Comment: @Venkatesh yes even my insert is not working. strange

Comment: @jazy1992 Yes, but I am talking about a transaction - code that can rollback *changes* you're making. Are you sure that you're accessing the same database from your code and Access? Do you close Access before you access the database?

Comment: @Thorsten This is the the first point in my program that interacts with my database. I always ensure that my access database is closed before i run my program to avoid any consistency issues. Can i clarify with you if its possible to run multiple queries in a single dbconnection?

Comment: Yes.. You can run multiple queries in single connection. that could not be an issue. Double check the database file you are referring in connection string is same as the file you are accessing in MS access.